# Show Alert dialog box while proceeding to next page in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have two view tabs named as topics and keywords,in each tab there is a table contains data.If the topic table is empty no need to enter the keyword page and redirect to the topic page and show an alert "plz enter topic data first" in a particular div.when we directly open topic tab,there is no need of this alert.

```
    if(isset($topic_data) && $topic_data == NULL)
    {

        redirect('topics?v1=no_topic');

    }
```

this is my keyword controller code.Then i get this value in topic controller

```
    $get_data = $this->input->get();


    if($get_data != "" && !isset($get_data))
    {

        echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert_box('failed', ' lang('add_topic')', '#msg');</script>";
    }
```

but it wont works.

there is div  in topic view part.

Comment: `$get_data = $this->input->get();` your get is empty you need to pass your get parameter in `$get_data = $this->input->get('your_parameter');`

Comment: as so far i know that can be done with AngularJS

Comment: I got the $get_data value but the alert not working.I already done it with session - flashdata.but i want to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `GET` requests are enabled in your `config.php` using the following settings:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

And specify which attribute you want to store in the variable, as already mentioned by @Saty.

```
$get_data = $this->input->get("v1");
```